# How to separate development and production keys in Leiningen app on heroku?

Tags: heroku, clojure, leiningen

I want have two different sets of API keys for development and production and I want to use them automatically depending on whether the app is run locally or on heroku.

For nodejs apps, I do the following:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
// ./prod contains the production keys
module.exports = require('./prod');
} else {
// ./dev contains the development keys
module.exports = require('./dev');
}
```

How to do something similar in a Clojure Leiningen app? What would the process.env.NODE_ENV analogue be, and how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Clojure runs on JVM, so you could use java System class.  Assuming you have set APP_ENVIRONMENT variable in bash.

```clj
(if (= "production"
       (or (System/getenv "APP_ENVIRONMENT")
           "development"))
  (start/production)
  (start/development))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the cleanest solution would be to use the [environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ) library together with the `lein-environ` plugin.

With these you store development version of API keys in env vars in the leiningen dev profile and on production pass them as actual environment variables. E.g. you can have the following in your `project.clj`:

```
(defproject ...
...
:profiles {:dev {:env {:my-api-key "whatever-dev" } } }
...)
```

On the production environment you could simply set an environment variable MY_API_KEY to "whatever-prod".

In your code you will access the key like this:

```
(require '[environ.core :refer [env]])
(env :my-api-key) ;; would yield "whatever-dev" on dev and "whatever-prod" on prod environment
```

In particular, this allows you not to store the production keys under source control.

`environ` provides a couple more options - in particular with env files, which may also fit your needs. Do check its capabilities.

If you also need access to environment variables in your CLJS (on frontend), you can't simply access environment variables there indeed (because there's no such thing as environment anymore - the code runs on the client).

Still, if you just wish to drop the values into the resulting js during compilation, you can use environ + a macro for that. You will write a macro in a clj file that just returns the env var and then refer it in your cljs file. During compilation the appropriate value will be injected.

In a clj file:

```
(ns yourns.environment
  (:require [environ.core :refer [env]]))

(defmacro my-api-key []
  (env :my-api-key))
```

In cljs:

```
(ns yourns.core
 (:require-macros [yourns.environment :refer [my-api-key]))

(my-api-key) ;; will return the appropriate value
```

Note, however, again that the variable value will be injected in compile time and can't be changed later.

Please see [here](https://github.com/asciinema/asciinema-player/commit/facc64737155765200f8dcba5dc2a0fe58e65fc7) for a complete code example.

Comment: using this doesn't work in cljs files. I get the error:


Failed to compile build :app from ["src/cljs" "src/cljc" "dev"] in 1.907 seconds.
----  Could not Analyze  src/cljs/myapp/events.cljs  ----

  No such namespace: environ.core, could not locate environ/core.cljs, environ/core.cljc, or JavaScript source providing "environ.core" 

----  Analysis Error : Please see src/cljs/myapp/events.cljs  ----
Figwheel: Starting CSS Watcher for paths  ["resources/public/css"]
Started myapp on http://localhost:5000

------
How to separate prod and dev environments in cljs files?

Comment: @zengod there is a slightly more complicated way to extend this to js - please check the answer again, I updated it.

Comment: I have two cljs files that need the environment variable. I required the macros in the two files in exactly the same way (:require-macros...). It worked in the the events.cljs (using re-frame) file but showed "undeclared variable" in the views.cljs file. Why would that be, and how to fix it?

Comment: @zengod sounds really strange. Can you spot any differences between the files? Do they live in the same location in your project? Do they belong to the same project? Do you call the required macro in both of them absolutely the same way?

Comment: It only happens when I require two macros like so:
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]]
                   [vendo.environment :refer [vendo-url]]
                   )
But works when I only have one. How to require two macros then?

Comment: It should work (as stated here: https://clojurescript.org/about/differences) - I can't suggest anything without looking at your code. You may also experiment with (:require [nsns :refer-macros [yourmacro]]) - e.g. for one of them, but it looks like it won't help. Could you post somewhere a minimalistic example of your non-working code, so that I could run it?